# Error in attempting to assign values to a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, simulation

Here is my complete code:

```
N_trials <- 1000
N_steps <- 1000
destinations <- matrix[NA, nrow=N_trials, ncol=N_steps]
l1_distance <- numeric(N)


for(m in 1:N_trials) {
  destination <- c(0,0)
  for(n in 1:N_steps) {
    if(runif(1) < 1/4) {
      destination[1] <- destination[1] - 1
    }
    else if(runif(1) < 1/2) {
      dstination[1] <- destination[1] + 1
    }
    else if(runif(1) < 3/4) {
      dstination[2] <- destination[2] + 1
    }
    else if(runif(1) < 1) {
      dstination[2] <- destination[2] - 1
    }
  }
  destinations[[m,1]] <- destination[1]
  destinations[[m,2]] <- destination[2]


l1_distance <- abs(destinations[N_trials][1]) + abs(destinations[N_trials][2])

}

print(mean(l1_distance))
```

Essentially, `destination` is a vector that starts at (0,0) and with probability 1/4 moves to an adjacent square (in the l^1 metric) for `N_steps` iterations. `destinations` records the result of `destination` for each n in `1:N_trials`, so as to compute a point estimate for `destination`.

However, I am having the error

> Error in matrix[NA, nrow = N_trials, ncol = N_steps] : 
>     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I do not know what this error means or how to resolve it. All I want to do is update the value of `directions[m][1]` and `directions[m][2]` according to the result of `destination[1]` and `destination[2]`. Am I defining the matrix `destinations` incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the initialization of matrix to `matrix(NA, nrow=N_trials, ncol=N_steps)`.

Comment: Hmm, now I get that the elements of ```l1_distance``` are all ```NA```. and actually the same for the elements of ```destinations```.

Comment: I tried changing e.g. ```destinations[[m][1]]``` with ```destinations[m,1]``` and now I get ther error (Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'l' not found).

Comment: What is the correct syntax for accessing the (i,j) entry of matrix A? I believe that is the root of my problem.

Comment: Use A[i,j] to access to the i'th row and j'th column of matrix A.